# UITableView reloading table without updated information

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

So I have a UITable and whenever I change something in it, and hit save, the data gets sent over to my DJANGO database and saves all the information correctly. 
However, when I leave the view and then come back to it, the table does not pick up the current data from the database and displays the data I had before my save. Once again, the data saves correctly in my database but I guess the array that stores the data locally does not update? I am using a navigation view and I am performing a segue to display the table. 
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class LifestyleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - View lifecycle

    var isOns: [Int] = []
    var chunks: [[Int]] = [[],[]]

    let emojiUnicodesMale: Array = [["", "⚽⚾", "️", "", "", "\u{1F483}", "\u{1F3AE}"], ["\u{1F4AA}", "\u{1F3C0}", "\u{1F3BE}", "\u{26BD}", "\u{26BE}", "\u{1F3B5}", "\u{1F3B1}"], ["\u{1F3A8}", "\u{1F3A4}", "\u{1F3A6}", "\u{1F3A3}", "\u{1F37B}", "\u{1F355}", "\u{1F3B3}"]]

    let emojiUnicodesFemale: Array = [["", "⚽⚾", "️", "", "", "\u{1F483}", "\u{1F3AE}"], ["\u{1F4AA}", "\u{1F3C0}", "\u{1F3BE}", "\u{26BD}", "\u{26BE}", "\u{1F3B5}", "\u{1F3B1}"],["\u{1F3A8}", "\u{1F3A4}", "\u{1F3A6}", "\u{1F3A3}", "\u{1F37B}", "\u{1F355}", "\u{1F3B3}"]]

    let emojiDescriptions: Array = [["Clothing Shopping", "Sport", "Tech", "Grocery", "Reading", "Dancing", "Games"], ["Gym Workout", "Basketball", "Tennis", "Football", "Baseball", "Music", "Snorker"], ["Painting", "Singing", "Shooting", "Fishing", "Drinking", "Pizza Lover", "Bowling"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.tableView = UITableView(frame: self.tableView.frame, style: .grouped)
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        getLifestyle()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            getLifestyle()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getLifestyle()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if(section == 1) {
            return "Food"
        } else {
            return "Shopping"
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmojiCell", for: indexPath) as! EmojiTableViewCell
        if (User.currentUser.gender == "female") {
            cell.labelEmojiUnicode.text = emojiUnicodesFemale[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.labelEmojiUnicode.text = emojiUnicodesMale[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.labelDescription.text = emojiDescriptions[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        if isOns.count > 0 {
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                switch(indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[0] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "0"
                case 1:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[1] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "1"
                case 2:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[2] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "2"
                case 3:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[3] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "3"
                case 4:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[4] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "4"
                case 5:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[5] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "5"
                case 6:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[6] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "6"
                default:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
                }

            }

            if indexPath.section == 1 {
                switch(indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[7] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "7"
                case 1:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[8] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "8"
                case 2:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[9] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "9"
                case 3:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[10] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "10"
                case 4:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[11] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "11"
                case 5:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[12] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "12"
                case 6:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[13] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "13"
                default:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
                }
            }

            if indexPath.section == 2 {
                switch(indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[14] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "14"
                case 1:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[15] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "15"
                case 2:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[16] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "16"
                case 3:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[17] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "17"
                case 4:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[18] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "18"
                case 5:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[19] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "19"
                case 6:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.isOn = isOns[20] == 0 ? false : true
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "20"
                default:
                    cell.buttonSwitch.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
                }
            }
            cell.buttonSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LifestyleTableViewController.switchChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    func getLifestyle() {
        isOns.removeAll()
        let lifestyle = User.currentUser.lifestyle
        let array = lifestyle?.components(separatedBy: ",")

        if let ary = array {
            for item in ary {
                isOns.append(Int(item)!)
            }
        }

        print(isOns)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func switchChanged(selectedSwitch: UISwitch) {

        if selectedSwitch.isOn {
            self.isOns[Int(selectedSwitch.restorationIdentifier!)!] = 1
        } else {
            self.isOns[Int(selectedSwitch.restorationIdentifier!)!] = 0
        }
    }

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {

        var lifestyle: String = ""
        for (index, item) in self.isOns.enumerated() {
            lifestyle += String(item)
            if index != self.isOns.count-1 {
                lifestyle += ","
            }
        }

        let params: [String: Any] = [
            "race": "",
            "phone": "",
            "lifestyle_info": lifestyle,
            "gender_pref": "",
            "race_pref": "",
            "budget_pref": "",
            "move_in_pref": ""
        ]

        APIManager.shared.updateUserProfile(params: params, completionHandler: { json in
            if json != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Successfully Saved!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "There is error saving your lifestyle info!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Error", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Maybe there is something wrong with my getLifeStyle()? Or maybe the table isn't being reloaded and the array isn't being updated.
I am lost, I have tried everything. I really do not know what it could be.

Comment: what is the output of your ` print(isOns)` in the `getLifestyle` method? are the values the correct (new) ones?

Comment: When you first load up the application, the values are correct. So if I were to change the settings, then save, and close and open the application. The values would be the updated ones. But if I were to just hit the back button and then come back to the settings, the values would be the old ones before the save. @Nef10

Comment: But the database has the updated data. So I am assuming my array is just not being updated correctly. @Nef10

Comment: The code here looks straight forward and ok. Please check the data before you are pushing this TableViewController. The table shows the data from `let lifestyle = User.currentUser.lifestyle`. Please check if the data in currentUser.lifestyle is updated.

Comment: It looks like the data in lifestyle is not being updated. Do you know how I can make it update with current data that is in my database? @dRAGONAIR

Comment: @dRAGONAIR got it up and running using my APIManager. I had to manually call a new JSON to be created every time that table was loaded so that the data is updated.